# Solrcloud multicore configuration

Tags: solr, lucene, multicore, sharding, solrcloud

I have a standalone **Solr** instance with 4 different cores working fine using the embedded Jetty server. I configured the cores for v4.10.3 but since I moved to v5.1 and all seems to work fine without any changes.

Before going into production, I need to set it up as a *Solrcloud installation, initially with 2 nodes (two different machines) with 1 shard per node* (to keep it simple). I have been trying to get it to work but I have not been able to do it.

I tried to run it like this (I think using start.jar is not the preferred way), having read that Solr will look for multiple configured cores in any nested folders (which works for standalone Solr):

```
java -DzkRun -DnumShards=2 -Dbootstrap_confdir=solr/ -jar start.jar
```

but that did not work, it does not find the needed `solrconfig.xml` file.

My Solr directory looks like this:
[image: 4 cores Solr folder]

My solr.xml file is the standard one:

```
<solr>

  <solrcloud>
    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:0}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:0}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```

Each core looks like this:
[image: a core config]

And the core.properties just has the name of the core:

```
name=users
```

**My question is:**

- How do I start Solrcloud v5.1 so the 4 cores are picked up?

Comment: @Lalit patadiya please stop making edit only removing Thank you text from the question.Focus on editing question for more readability and improvements. Removing thank you text does not improve question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SolrCloud each of your **Core** will become a **Collection**.

Each Collection will have its own set of Config Files and data.

You might find this helpful [Moving multi-core SOLR instance to cloud](http://volodk.blogspot.com/2013/08/moving-multi-core-solr-instance-to-cloud.html)

Solr 5.0 (onwards) has made some changes on how to create a SolrCloud setup with shards, and how to add collections etc.

Everything listed below is my understanding of the Solr Reference Guide. I will highly recommend going through it thoroughly. 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Apache+Solr+Reference+Guide

I setup my servers on a Linux(CentOS) server, but the steps can be used to setup solr on Windows system also. For example, there is `solr.cmd` file instead of `solr.sh`

Here are the steps I followed to create a simple two shard SolrCloud setup.

- Setup the zookeeper ensemble. I am assuming you are trying to use the
  embedded ZK in solr.     For a production system, it is highly
  recommended to create a external ZK ensemble. You can find steps to install a external ensemble in [this section of reference guid](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble)
- Download solr to `/opt` folder.
- Extract the install file ONLY.

  `tar xzf solr-5.0.0.tgz solr-5.0.0/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip components=2`
- This command will **install** solr on your system

  `sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-5.0.0.tgz`
- The above command will create a new user called "solr" if it does not exist.
- These are some of the default options it will assume. You can view this in `/var/solr/solr.in.sh` . This is the include file where you can specify other options.

  ```
      * SOLR_PID_DIR=/var/solr
      * SOLR_HOME=/var/solr/data
      * LOG4J_PROPS=/var/solr/log4j.properties
      * SOLR_LOGS_DIR=/var/solr/logs
      * SOLR_PORT=8983
  ```
- Running `install_solr_service start` in the above step will start a solr server. Stop the server using `service solr stop` before doing any of the changes below.
- Change Java heap value

  `SOLR_HEAP="3g"`

  This will set Xmx and Xms as 3GB .  (optional)
  This variable is not mentioned in the solr.in.sh file in Solr 5.1 . Its a bug and has been fixed, will be released in next version.
- `SOLR_MODE="solrcloud"` **Required**

  this is what you need start solr in cloud mode.
- `ZK_HOST=ZK1:2181,ZK2:2181,ZK3:2181` **Required**

  (replace zk with you zookeeper host names)
- Running the `install_solr_service.sh` command also creates a init.d file as `/etc/init.d/solr`
- This `init.d` script in turn calls the `/opt/solr/bin/solr` script and includes all the variables from `/var/solr/solr.in.sh`
- Once you have made the above changes, start solr again using `service solr start`
- You can check the status using `service solr status`

**Creating Collections Shards and Replicas**
 -  All shard, collection, replica related commands are now made using Collections API.

- Before creating a collection a config folder should be uploaded to ZK . 
  This can be done using the zkcli.sh script in the solr folder (not on the zookeeper servers)
  Folder: `/opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts`
- The command to upload the confg folder is

`sh zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181 -confname yourconfigname -confdir /var/solr/configs/conf`

**You will run this command 4 times for each of your 4 cores, each time changing the path of the conf folder and config name.**

- This will upload all the config files in conf folder with the name 'yourconfigname' in zookeeper.

**Creating a collection**
I used the following command to create a new collection.

http://1.1.1.1:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=yourcollectionname&numShards=2&replicationFactor=1&maxShardsPerNode=1&createNodeSet=1.1.1.1:8983_solr,2.2.2.2:8983_solr&collection.configName=yourconfigname

Happy Searching!

Comment: Thank you @jay, you definitely cleared some lack of concept I had. Now I have a problem with one of my nodes (collection) not starting properly due to an error on a SolrEventListener custom class I have. It worked fine on 4.10.3 standalone, but it fails on 5.2 cloud. I'll do some research and maybe post a new question about it. I have the feeling that development in Solr is much faster that updating the docs.

Comment: @s1m3n You might also find a solution by searching in mailing list for the error you are getting. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-f472067.html or check for existing Jira issues - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/solr/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel.

Comment: I tried #solr on irc.freenode.net with no luck and the mailing list is very convoluted from my point of view. I'll try Jira from now on. Thanks.

Comment: And of course, being able to offer points increases the chances of someone posting a great answer like yours!

Answer (score 1):

SolrCloud does not use configuration files stored in core `conf` directory. To make your cores visible in SolrCloud structure you need to upload the configuration files to ZooKeeper and keep it manage the files to you. All the time a Solr instance comes up it get the configuration files stored in ZooKeeper. This way your cores doesn't need to have `conf` directory to work. To upload your core configuration files to ZooKeeper follow the link bellow and take a look at `Upload a configuration directory`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Command+Line+Utilities