# Extending a solr collection across multiple machines

Tags: solr, server, distributed-computing, sharding, solrcloud

I am trying to set up a [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) collection that extends across multiple servers. If I am correct in understanding things, I am able to set up a collection, which consists of shards. Those shards consist of replicas, which is correspond to cores. Please correct any holes in my understanding of this.

Ok.

So I've got solr set up and am able to create a collection on machine one by doing this.

```
bin/solr create_collection -c test_collection -shards 2 -replicationFactor 2 -d server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf
```

This appears to do something right, I am able to check the health and see something. I input

```
bin/solr healthcheck -c test_collection
```

and I see the shard information.

Now what I want to do, and this is the part I am stuck on, is to take this collection that I have created, and extend it across multiple servers. I'm not sure if I understand how this works correctly, but I think what I want to do is put shard1 on machine1, and shard2 on machine2.

I can't really figure out how to do this based on the documentation, although I am pretty sure this is what SolrCloud is meant to solve. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction with this...? Either a way to extend the collection across multiple servers or a reason for not doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `-shards 2`, you're saying that you want your collection to be split across two servers already. `-replicationFactor 2` says that you want those shards present on at least two servers as well.

A shard is a piece of the collection - without a shard, you won't have access to all the documents. The replicationFactor indicates how many copies should be made available of the same shard (or "partition" which some times is used to represent the piece of the index) in the collection, so two shards with two replicas will end up with four "cores" distributed across the available servers (these "cores" are managed internally by Solr).

Start a set of new SolrCloud instances in the same cluster and you should see that the documents are spread across your nodes as expected.

Comment: How would I ensure that they are part of the same cluster? For background, I am running a solr instance (node?) on 2 different docker containers.. I have got things set up so that I can ssh between the containers, so for all intents and purposes they are two separate machines. Do you know how I would set up one server/shard on one container, and one server/shard on the other?

Comment: Again, my understanding of all of this is somewhat limited so I appreciate  your patience :)

Comment: the replicationFactor and shard number ensures that automagically. You'll have to make sure they're both using the same zookeeper ensemble, as that's what Solr uses to coordinate the cluster.

Comment: ok. So it sounds like I would need to get the zookeeper stuff setup before I make attempt to create a collection? How would I do that? Is it a part of the "bin/solr start -cloud" command?

Comment: SolrCloud can use an embedded ZooKeeper, but it's highly recommended to set up your own ensemble instead. Three servers are a minimum to get a decent zookeeper setup. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble

Comment: I just want to get things working with the embedded ZooKeeper if possible.. I tried starting the second solr instance with the -z flag set to the IP address of the first machine on port 9983... does this sound sane? I guess if I can't get the embedded instance to work I will try setting up my own ZooKeeper stuff but I want to keep going things simple as possible for now.

Comment: You might find part of this answer helpful You might find part of this answer useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/30721788/689625

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm not sure what I was really doing incorrect before, but I was able to start to instances of solr on different servers, and connect them via the embedded instance of zookeeper. This thread has definitely given me a better standing of how it all fits together

Answer (score 1):

As said before, the shards are pieces of the collection (data) in actual servers.

When you ran the command, you've asked that your collection will be split into 2 machines - at that point in time.

Once you add more machines to the mix, (by registering them to the same zookeeper), you can use the collection API to manage and add them to the fold as well.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API

You can split shards into 2 (or more) new shards.

You can create new shards, or delete shards.

The question of course - is how do the documents split among the shards?

When you create the collection, you can define a router.name

```
router.name  - The router name that will be used. 
The router defines how documents will be distributed among the shards. 
The value can be either implicit, which uses an internal default hash, 
or compositeId, which allows defining the specific shard to assign documents to.     
When using the 'implicit' router, the shards parameter is required. 
When using the 'compositeId' router, the numShards parameter is required.
For more information, see also the section Document Routing.
```

What this means - is that you can define the number of shards (like you did) or go to a totally different approach which distinguishes shards by a prefix in the document id.

For more information about the second approach see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud#ShardsandIndexingDatainSolrCloud-DocumentRouting

Comment: thanks for the response Uri. I could only accept one answer, but I appreciate your detailed response. I have a much better understanding of how to connect these solr cores across multiple servers, and you were definitely a part of that.